# How do I insert nested objects correctly in Ef

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I had a problem trying to add object from dto.

I have a DTO like this

```
  public class CustomerCourseSessionDto : IDto
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    public int? ConnectorId { get; set; } 
    public List<SomeObject>? SomeObject { get; set; }
    public List<OtherObject>? OtherObject { get; set; }
  }
```

and I'm trying to insert this DTO sent from the UI. I'm using a loop(foreach) for this, but it didn't feel right to me.

Maybe entityframework suggests a method for this, idk...

Other objects are like this

```
 public class SomeObject: IEntity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ConnectorId { get; set; } 
  }
```

```
 public class OtherObject: IEntity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ConnectorId { get; set; } 
  }
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Here is where I use the loop:

```
    [TransactionScopeAspect]
        public IResult AddWithDto(CustomerCourseSessionDto courseSessionDto)
        {
    
          foreach (var item in courseSessionDto.Participants)
          {
            _someObjectService.Add(item);
          }
    
          foreach (var item in courseSessionDto.Lessons)
          {
            _otherObjectService.Add(item);
          }
    
          _customerCourseSessionDal.Add(new CustomerCourseSession
          {
            Id = courseSessionDto.Id,
            CustomerCourseId = courseSessionDto.CustomerCourseId,
          
          });
          return SuccessResult with message ;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you're actually using? The one you mention in "I'm using a loop(foreach) for this".

Comment: Question edit with loop code

Comment: *Remove* all this code and that `TransactionScopeAspect`. Just `someContext.CourseSession.Add(sessionAndAll);` is enough. That will add all related objects in the `Added` state. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work, so when `SaveChanges` is called all changes will be persisted in a single database transaction

Comment: BTW there's no EF Core in the question. No DbContext. `TransactionScopeAspect` isn't an EF Core attribute nor would it matter. All pending changes are saved with `SaveChanges`. There are multiple "services" which means that either EF isn't used at all, or it's used incorrectly. At best those "services" are just wrappers over an injected DbContext

Comment: This code is working well but is there any other way to do it without loop?

Comment: That's not EF code. There's no need for any loop. EF Core doesn't have services. This code isn't related to the question. Where's the DbContext-derived class? Where's the call to `SaveChanges` ?

Comment: It's actually an Ef question because these services run SaveChanges in the background. I can expand the question if you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your entities to have a link to each table using foreign keys.

```
    public class CustomerCourseSession
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CourseParticipant> Participants { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CourseLesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    }

    public class CourseParticipant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerCourseSessionId { get; set; } // Foreign Key from CustomerCourseSession
        // other fields here
        
        public virtual CustomerCourseSession CustomerCourseSession { get; set;}
    }
    
    public class CourseLesson
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerCourseSessionId { get; set; } // Foreign Key from CustomerCourseSession
        // other fields here
        
        public virtual CustomerCourseSession CustomerCourseSession { get; set;}
        
    }
```

Then you can just call:

```
var entity = MapDtoToEntity(courseSessionDto);

_dbContext.CustomerCourseSessions.Add(entity);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I changed my design like you say but it didn't work :S

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? can you post some of you code?

Comment: Of course I can , which part exactly ?